# What holes are played on a diatonic harp with notation "+6#3"?

Tags: harmonica

I found a blues riff tab that goes like this:

```
-2 -3b +4 -4b  +6#3     -4b -3 -2
```

What does it mean to blow on the sixth hole and block the third?  Does that mean you are blowing in 4, 5, and 6?  Why not just write `+456`?

Answer (score 1):

`+6#3` means to blow out through holes 6 and 3, and only holes 6 and 3, which form an octave.  The # means to use your tongue to block holes 4 and 5.